# finding API server for free historic data for online digital stock market charts

Tags: javascript

I want to draw stock market charts for **(Bitcoin & Ethereum & others)** with `React & chart.js`
but the problem is that what ever `API server` I found needs to pay or does not provide historic data
!!

any advice ???

Comment: "any advice ?" ... Pay them.

Comment: Who pays for the storage and data transfer costs if it's free?